# How to resize the width of bootstrap modal.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, modal-dialog, width

downloaded the  bootstrap.min.css on the bootstrap site

but I encountered a problem which I couldnt edit the width of the modal
how do you adjust the width?

tried searching but couldn't find the answer

here is a sample picture I wanted the width to shrink
http://i58.tinypic.com/iwnns8.png

Comment: I really ned help guys :'(

Answer (score 0):

don't try to set the size manualy because it will make it useless on iphone.
This works for me for all cases. You can change the class name and sizes... Happy coding;)

```
body .modal.large {
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto; 
}
```